# Promehteus histogram_quatile() is producing inaccurate estimate of duration of requests

Tags: go, histogram, prometheus, metrics

I am trying to wrap my head around Prometheus histograms and histogram_quantile() and estimate errors.

We've set up request duration metrics for a service, but I keep seeing inaccurate duration on our Grafana graph in comparison to our logs(which prints duration). In other words, I see one value passed to Prometheus collector and a another bigger value after a query in Grafana. When I say bigger, I mean the logs says request took 1.2sec, but Grafana shows it took somewhere around 2.3sec(for 99th percentile).

- Here is the query(same one is used for .95 and .50):

```
histogram_quantile(0.99,sum(rate(service_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="some path"}[$__rate_interval])) by (le))
```

- Here are the buckets:

```
var durationTimeBucketsInSeconds = []float64{.01, .025, .05, .1, .25, .5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10}
```

I did some research and found out about https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#errors-of-quantile-estimation

**Is there anyway to estimate closer to the real value, like adjusting buckets?**